# Multiple classes in 1 file only 1 class accessible

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes in 1 file. I have to put them all in 1 file because of company standards for the program I'm writing something for. Is there some way to only make 1 class in the file accessible?

Nobody needs to see the other classes.

Comment: you can make class private , that is only way to hide it or internal if you just want visibility till assembly or other way create nested classes

Comment: @ Pranay Rana The problem is that other classes in the file need to be able to acces different classes. This means i cant put them on private. and if i put them on internal i can still create object from those classes.

Comment: Putting all classes in a single file is a *very* unusual requirement - are you absolutely sure this is what has been asked of you? Not only is it unusual, I'd consider it very bad practice and counter productive. Now, it may have been asked of you to create a single library, that's a different question...

Comment: Try make any class you wanna access in same Namespace with your some public class so only that public class and other class in same namespace can access its

Comment: @DavidG yes im shure its wats asked of me. I did ask if i realy had to do that. But im in an internship and dont wana poke around to much :) + Thats how they did it with everything else int there programm so i will just stick with wat they tell me to do and to wat is the standard here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the purpose. If the only "accessible" class would simply use the functionalities of the other classes, then that class needs to be `public`, and the rest could be `private`.

If you have properties in that classes which are types of the other, they cannot be `private` then.

Comment: @RitwikSen Don't beg for answers to be accepted and/or voted please

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any code reviewing tools like stylcop  etc. then it will force you to have one class file with only one declared class over there. You can't get rid of this.
But since you are actively using only one class then there are couple of option you have :-

1. You can make you class private
2. Use different data structure like struct etc to remove the use of your additional classes.